# In the full virtualization, how to do binary translation for "popf" instruction in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, virtualization, instructions

I'm studying about virtualization.(I'm a undergraduated student)

In CPU **Full virtualization**, as far as I know, x86 was difficult to be virtualized because it has about 17 **sensitive but unprivileged** instructions.(e.g., `popf`)

So, they used "binary translation" to make these instructions to be "trapped".(because if these instructions run on unprivileged level, it will not trap so be dangerous)

My question is...

1. In some articles, they said that binary translation is used for making privileged instructions "not" to be trapped.(removing trap overhead)

For example, `cli` -> `and $0xfd, %gs:vcpu.flags`

Which one is right?

2. Can you give me a sample target code for popf?

`popf` -> ?

Comment: `popf` can set or clear important flags like IF and TF that affect how the guest machine executes.  Also AC, alignment-checking.  If you're virtualizing a guest that has its own interrupt handlers, you can't just clear those flags.  I'm not sure there's anything plausible you could inline.  Although if you already have `%gs:vcpu.flags`, can you just `pop %gs:vcpu.flags` to pop into that?  Not that simple; you have to know if the guest is in user-space or not: `IF` isn't updated except in kernel mode (ring aka CPL=0). https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/popf:popfd:popfq

Comment: It's probably more code than you want to actually inline; you'd probably want to call a helper function.  (Except you'd need to call through a special kind of far call to change stacks if you don't want to corrupt space below ESP/RSP for the guest, in case it's implementing an ABI with a red-zone.  Or some other trick maybe involving static storage.)

Comment: "Which one is right?" - both are right. Sometimes there are nonprivileged instructions that you want to trap. Sometimes there are privileged instructions that you don't want to trap.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm always so grateful for your answers. Sorry I didn't fully understand what you said, but to summarize what you said, I can add a few more lines of code that behave like(emulate) `popf`, or add code that calls a helper function that can handle things like this?(I know that `popf` makes different results depending on privilege level. So, I understood that these instructions should be binary translated.)

Comment: Behaving differently depending on privilege level means it's a *lot* of code (unless you can prove that a certain instance of it is only ever going to run in the same mode, not e.g. a page of memory that's sometimes executed by the kernel and sometimes by user-space).  So you probably wouldn't want to inline it (in binary translation).  And it's going to need some scratch space for temporaries, although you might be able to use static storage for that.  Fortunately it's ok to overwrite FLAGS for conditional branching since you're about to `popf`.

Comment: (You'd probably still end with a real `popf` after sanitizing the value you're going to `popf`, then restore stack contents below ESP/RSP, unless you can assume the guest stack contents below RSP can be asynchronously clobbered by the VM.)